# Find class definition in a bunch of swf files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm sorry, but I must warn that I never really worked with flash. This is a reverse-engineering project.

Now application I'm inspecting throws this error in it's log file:

```
2/17/2015 02:14:52.277 [ERROR] com.riotgames.platform.gameclient.utils.FileSerializer Unable to read file: C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\projects\lol_air_client\releases\0.0.1.129\deploy\preferences\MXXIV.properties
```

I want to find out why this error is thrown, which means `FileSerializer` class. I downloaded JPEXS Free swf decompiler and had a look on project files. The problem is that there's a LOT of these files. Much more than you can see on this image.

[image: image description]

Opening every file and checking whether the class is there isn't very effective. I had false hopes many times:

[image: image description]

My question therefore is: **How can I find the definition of the class mentioned in the log?**

Comment: I have Far Manager installed for many file-related tasks so I just use its Search function that is activated by Alt-F7. It can search for any filename starting from current directory and all subdirs, and also checks if a given string exists inside the file.

Comment: I tried this. But the files are compiled and thought the string MUST be in them, I found nothing. I finally found the class after decompiling many files manually and then searching in the sources - but that meant I no more knew what is the origin of that source file.